# What are uses of fossils?

Tags: evolution

What are the geological uses of fossils and how could it be utilised?

From [The Institute for Creation Science](http://www.icr.org/article/508/):

> Fossils are typically found in sedimentary rock, almost all of which were originally deposited as sediments by moving water. Subsequent processes hardened them into sedimentary rock, as overlying pressure squeezed the water out and the grains were cemented together. Often plants and animals were trapped, being buried in the sediments. As the sediments hardened into sedimentary rock, the dead things hardened into fossils.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about geology.

Comment: What exactly to you mean by uses?

Comment: Utilized by whom? I use one as a paperweight.

Comment: That is a direct quote from a [creation science](http://www.icr.org/article/508/) website, a rather disreputable source.

Comment: @Amory did you read that article? It contains this wonderful gem of logic: "One more thing. These catastrophically deposited marine fossils, entombed as they are in regionally extensive sedimentary rock, are all found on the continents! There are hardly any marine fossils found in the deep ocean basins." So, fossils are found more often on the continents than in the deep ocean, and this has nothing to do with the fact that it's a wee bit more difficult to search the bottom of the ocean than to search my back yard! Ain't the bible grand?

Comment: Beautiful!  I think my favorite was "...these fossils were found as creationists did their research from a creationist/flood perspective. They found what evolutionist/uniformitarian seekers missed."  As if.

Comment: I want o lmfao because ...

Answer (score 2):

Since you're talking about Geo, then the short answer to that would be:

To check how long such specie (animals or plants) existed on the planet (earth obviously)!

**For example:** You came to know about Dinosaurs using the Fossils and you made up their whole skeleton and then using your imagination you created the body.

**Usage:**

Keeping the above example in mind, fossils are used to know the period of extinction of the living being or the existance or both.

Fossils are sometimes used as Fossil fuel too, but that's in liquid form when they are decomposed anaerobically by the bacteria and all that info, please check the reference for this.

And what is the last paragraph about? Some information eh? I was not able to understand its usage and utility to the question! Sorry :)

#### Reference

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fossil_fuel (Fossil Fuel)